# How to check if specific key combinations are enabled?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I am on Linux and have a RK61 mechanical keyboard. Since this keyboard does not have separate arrow keys you need to press STRG + ENTER to access the arrow keys or to disable them. Now the problem is that you don't know if the arrow keys are enabled or are disabled since there is no indicator for that. Is there any option to know if the keyboard combination is enabled? Is there any program for detecting that?